# Значение префикса "on" в именах методов в Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Что означает префикс "on" в названиях методов в Android. Например, метод onDraw(). У меня есть, конечно, предположения, но хотелось бы точную информацию. В интернете не получилось найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приставкой on- обозначаются методы-колбэки (методы интерфейсов обратного вызова). Как правило реализация колбэка - это реализация какого то действия или реакции на событие.

Сам метод интерфейса не имеет кода, он реализуется при вызове этого интерфейса и должен содержать действия, соответствующие произошедшему. Приставка on- как раз указывает, что это реакция на событие и в метод требуется написать код, выполняемый при этом действии.

Например, метод-колбэк onClick() интерфейса обратного вызова OnClickListener.  Буквально название метода значит - приКлике,  то есть такие методы имеют разную реализацию действий в том или ином случае, а не всегда определенный набор команд, как "обычные" методы и вызывается он именно при реакции на событие, а не в произвольном месте кода программистом.

Так же следует понимать, что это просто соглашение для удобства понимания назначения метода. Сама по себе приставка on- не наделяет метод какими то свойствами.

Answer (score 6):

Так обозначают те методы, которые вызываются только при воздействии на что-то пользователем. А методы без префикса вы можете вызвать где хотите и когда хотите. Например onClick.  Он вызывается только при нажатии на объект.

Answer (score 2):

При переводе можете заменять "on" на предлог "при":

- При рисовании;
- При нажатии;
- При соединении;

и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Любой переводчик Вам ответит, что "on" значит "на" или "по". Например, `onCreate()` - метод в классе `Activity`, выполняемый по инициализации (создании) экземпляра.

Подытожим, методы начинаются на `on`, если они отвечают на какое-либо событие (необязательно инициированного пользователем).

Теоретически, Вы можете создать свой метод, который начинается на `on`, но который не будет привязан к событию. Приставка не является обязательной, однако её используют для того, чтобы код был понятным и легкочитаемым.

Если интересно, то я нашёл  [обратный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14112241) на английском StackOverflow.